# Build facturx invoice with Mustang library

Tags: java, invoice

I do try to build a factur-x using Mustang library.
For minimum profile, a Buyer legal registration identifier is required.

For this I build a trade party object:

```
    TradeParty recipient = new TradeParty(
            "My Client",
            "My address",
            "06000",
            "City",
            "FR")
            .setID("123 456 789 10111");
```

My issue is the following:

- I'm able to build an XML (that's what I want)
- I'm not able to set the organization ID and pass the schemeID to 0002 (for french factur-X).
- I didn't find how to set

Here is what is expected:

```
<ram:SpecifiedLegalOrganization>
   <ram:ID schemeID="0002">123 456 789 10111</ram:ID>
</ram:SpecifiedLegalOrganization>
```

I do also have to set the business process type, which is specific for Chorus Pro (in france):

```
<ram:BusinessProcessSpecifiedDocumentContextParameter>
   <ram:ID>A1</ram:ID>
</ram:BusinessProcessSpecifiedDocumentContextParameter>
```

Here, A1 means invoice deposit, A2 means prepaid invoice deposit, ... By default (in the absence of this field), the case A1 is applied.

The output for recipient :

```
  <ram:BuyerTradeParty>
    <ram:ID>123 456 789 10111</ram:ID>
    <ram:Name>My Client</ram:Name>
    <ram:PostalTradeAddress>
      <ram:PostcodeCode>06000</ram:PostcodeCode>
      <ram:LineOne>My address</ram:LineOne>
      <ram:CityName>City</ram:CityName>
      <ram:CountryID>FR</ram:CountryID>
    </ram:PostalTradeAddress>
  </ram:BuyerTradeParty>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SpecifiedLegalOrganisation/ID has been added to Mustang 2.5 https://www.mustangproject.org/mustang-2-5-0/, please report an issue via https://github.com/ZUGFeRD/mustangproject/issues if there are further requirements vis á vis Chorus Pro I am not aware of.

Answer (score 1):

as you indicated (and as described in the english FX spec 1.05 e.g. on page 115 as well as in the technical annex to ZUGFeRD with a cardinality 0..1) BT-23, i.e. ram:BusinessProcessSpecifiedDocumentContextParameter is optional so you can just omit it unless you need other values. Do you require to set anything nonstandard here?

However, so far nobody ever requested being able to set the legalorganisation +ID and scheme ID, which means that probably nobody ever used Mustang so far to write invoices vis á vis the french authorities (only to german ones or for factur-x B2B invoices).

However, I just [added the possibility](https://github.com/ZUGFeRD/mustangproject/commit/ddb71f9ed55f9ab50cd91e3754a80a52b81ca1ca), you can now use someTradeParty.setLegalOrganisation(new LegalOrganisation("0815", "0002")). This will become part of the next release, could you please confirm that this works and is all you need?

Comment: Please do not add signatures to Stack Overflow answers